# How do I group categories in a grouped barplot from a list of discrete objects?

Tags: r

Let's say I want to make a barplot of the average weight of different things.  One category is animals, another category is cars. In the animals category I have a cat, a dog, and a goldfish, and in the cars category I have a Prius and truck.  How do I group the animals' weights together and the cars' weights together on a barplot in R?  Every example I have seen of 'grouped barplots' has groups that are expected to be in each category.

Here's how I've tried to do it so far:

```
d <- data.frame(categories = c("animal", "animal", "animal","car", "car"),
        centers = c("dog", "cat", "fish", "prius", "truck"),
        means = c(23, 24, 28, 19, 40),
        standardErrors = c(1.2, 1.7, 0.9, 0.4, 1),
        mins = c(21, 20, 20, 16, 30),
        maxes = c(27, 29, 30, 32, 44),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=categories, y=means, fill=centers)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

I get the following error: `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class`numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=categories, y=means, fill=centers)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity',position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

You need to add: stat='identity' to geom_bar